# Where does the environment lie that contains the PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT environment variable?

Tags: php, xampp, environment-variables, php-ini, memory-limit

I'm using **Windows 10 Home Single Language** operating system on my machine. It's a **64-bit Operating System** running on a **x64-based processor**.

I've installed the latest version ox **XAMPP(Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.5 )** on my machine.

In the PHP Manual I come across following code example saying [***php.ini* Environment Variables**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#example-51)

```
; PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT is taken from environment
memory_limit = ${PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT}
```

In the above example, I'm not understanding 'from environment' means exactly from where this `PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT` variable is taken. Where does this so called 'Environment and its Variables' lie?

Does this so called 'Environment' contain any other variables than `PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT`?

Answer (score 0):

To know where the environment variables lie, you can run `phpinfo()` and see under the **Environment** section. Of course it contains more than one variable.

Comment: I just checked the 'Environment' section from the output of phpinfo() but I couldn't find the so called environment variable PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT in it.

Comment: Then your environment does not have that variable. Is your memory limit taken from the environment? It's supposed to be 
memory_limit = 128M. You can view your php.ini file to make sure that.

Comment: Yes, it has been set to 128 M. On what factors do the environment variables present depend upon? I also tried echo $_ENV['USERDOMAIN']; but it gave me output as 
Notice: Undefined index: USERDOMAIN. 'USERDOMAIN' is a variable present under the heading 'Environment ' in the output of phpinfo(). According to what you are saying it should have print the value of USERDOMAIN. Why this is happening then?

Comment: @SerialKisser Your $_ENV seems to be empty. You can still see the list of your environment variables using getenv() or in phpinfo(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Comment: Yes, it's empty. My question is related to the example from the manual. Where the value is set to the variable PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT? Is it different from the variables present in $_ENV global array?